# How to send iOS URL scheme through email to users

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, redirect, url-scheme

I have created a url scheme for my iOS app to pass some values when user clicks on it as bellow and it is working:

```
myapp://myapp/login?username=personaltester50
```

But what I need is to send this link via email to the user. When I copy/paste the link in browser it works and ask the user about opening the app but if I send the URL in email (no matter in body of email or as html), it doesn't work since the browser/email app will modify it to the following link:

```
http://myapp//myapp/login?username=userid...
```

Any idea? How can I have a link for my iOS url scheme in an email so the user can just click on it and it shows the message to open the app. I don't want to use any other third-party website to redirect the link or something like that.

Comment: You need to provide more information - How are you creating and sending the email?  I just sent an email from Exchange using Outlook for Mac that had a `myapp://myapp` style URL and it was received normally in iOS mail app (Gmail account).  Tapping the link opened my app

Comment: I used several (Outlook and Gamil). None is working. 
You are using Outlook app and send it as a hyperlink? And in Gmail app receive it as a correct link?

Comment: I just literally typed myApp://myApp into the email body and sent it.  On the receiving end, ios mail detected it as a URL and made it clickable